# Curve_fit not converging means...?

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I need to crossmatch a list of astronomical coordinates with different catalogues, and I want to decide a maximum radius for the crossmatch. This will avoid mismatches between my list and the catalogues.

To do this, I compute the separation between the best match with the catalogue for each object in my list. My initial list is supossed to be the position of a known object, but it could happend that it is not detected in the catalog, and my coordinates may suffer from small offsets.

They way I am computing the maximum radius is by fitting the gaussian kernel density of the separation with a gaussian, and use the center + 3sigmas value. The method works nicely for most of the cases, but when a small subsample of my list has an offset, I have two gaussians instead. In these cases, I will specify the max radius in a different way.

My problem is that when this happens, curve_fit can't normally do the fit with one gaussian. For a scientific publication, I will need to justify the "no fit" in curve_fit, and in which cases the "different way" is used. Could someone give me a hand on what this means in mathematical terms?

Answer (score 0):

There are varying lengths to which you can go justifying this or that fitting ansatz --- which strongly depends on the details of your specific case (eg: why do you expect a gaussian to work in a first place? to what depth you need/want to delve into why exactly a certain fitting procedure fails and what exactly is a fail etc).

If the question is really about the curve_fit and its failure to converge, then show us some code and some input data which demonstrate the problem.

If the question is about how to evaluate the goodness-of-fit, you're best off going back to the library and picking a good book on statistics.

If all you look for is way of justifying why in a certain case a gaussian is not a good fitting ansatz, one way would be to calculate the moments: for a gaussian distribution 1st, 2nd, 3rd and higher moments are [related to each other](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments) in a very precise way. If you can demonstrate that for your underlying data the relation between moments is very different, it sounds reasonable that these data can't be fit by a gaussian.